# How to clear cache for config entity after making changes?

Tags: 8, entities, hooks, configuration

We have a custom form `mymoduleForm` that has `mymodule.settings` which stores some values that we need to run some logic when calling `mymodule_preprocess_node()` hook. The form just has a text area where we insert URIs and use that in the `mymodule_preprocess_node` hook to perform some action.

We can store the values in a Config entity as expected (see below). When we make changes to the Config entity, we want to clear cache for the config entity as well. How can we clear the Config Entity's Cache after making changes?

Goal:

- When there are updates to the Config entity, clear the cache for the entity so that the latest entity is used in `mymodule_preprocess_node` hook.

Issue:

- When we make changes to the Config entity using the custom form, the logic that we need to run is not running with the latest settings.

What we have tried:

1. Tried adding [addCacheableDependency($form, $config);](http:////%20Ensure%20that%20edit%20forms%20have%20the%20correct%20cacheability%20metadata%20so%20they%20can%20%20%20%20%20//%20be%20cached.%20%20%20%20%20if%20(!$this-%3Eentity-%3EisNew())%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5CDrupal::service('renderer')-%3EaddCacheableDependency($form,%20$this-%3Eentity);%20%20%20%20%20%7D)  to the `buildForm()`, but it is not working.

**mymoduleForm.php**

```
class mymoduleForm extends ConfigFormBase {
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    if (!$this->entity->isNew()) {
        \Drupal::service('renderer')->addCacheableDependency($form, $this->entity);
      }

    $config = $this->config('mymodule.settings');

    $form['some_field'] = [
      '#type' => 'textarea',
      '#title' => $this->t('Some field title'),
      '#description' => $this->t('some description'),
      '#default_value' => $config->get('some_field'),
    ];

    return parent::buildForm($form, $form_state);
  }

  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $this->config('mymodule.settings'),
      ->set('some_field', $form_state->getValue('some_fields'))
      ->save();
  }
}
```

**mymodule_preprocess_node**

```
function mymodule_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $config = \Drupal::config('mymodule.settings');
  $config_value = $config->get('some_field');

  $library = 'mymodule/some-library';

  if($config_value == 'some_value') {
    $variables['#attached']['library'][] = $library;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you have to add the cacheable dependencies of the config object, not only to the form, but also to the render array in preprocess, so that the rendered output gets the correct cache data:

```
function mymodule_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $config = \Drupal::config('mymodule.settings');
  $config_value = $config->get('some_field');
  // add the cache tag, so that the output gets invalidated when the config is saved
  \Drupal::service('renderer')->addCacheableDependency($variables, $config);

  $library = 'mymodule/some-library';

  if($config_value == 'some_value') {
    $variables['#attached']['library'][] = $library;
  }
}
```

Comment: I think the dependencies from the form _should_ work without this. See eg. [`Drupal\search\Form\SearchBlockForm::buildForm()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21search%21src%21Form%21SearchBlockForm.php/function/SearchBlockForm%3A%3AbuildForm).

Comment: My bad, didn't read the question closely enough. +1!

Comment: @Andy, yes, this is the same problem I had while answering. Normally you don't need to add cache data to an administrative config form. But it is unclear what kind of form this is, so I edited the answer, because generally it is not a bad idea to add the cache data of the object to the form on which the form is based on.

Comment: @4k4 you have `$variables` instead of `$form`. was that intentional? I am trying to figure out if this `addCacheableDependency()` needs to happen after the `$config = $this->config('mymodule.settings');`

Comment: If this is a config form you probably don't need to add cache data to $form at all. But you need to do this in preprocess. I've edited the answer with the complete preprocess hook.

Comment: OK, after you've edited the question it's clear it is a config form, but then you need to remove the first three lines, because there is no $this->entity.

Comment: @4k4 i added the `addCacheableDependency()` right after the `$config = \Drupal::config('mymodule.settings');` but before i call any `$config->get('some_field')` and it looks to be working as i cleared cache and it was using the latest values.

Comment: @4k4 with further testing we have found this to be working now. However we had another question for which we created a separate question for [When to create schema while working with config entity?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/266680/when-to-create-schema-while-working-with-config-entity).