# How to clear the a block cache programmically

Tags: 8

I have a custom block that display some information from a custom configuration form.  I want the block to be cached, however, I want the block cache to be cleared every time I save the form.

I would like to do this in the `submitForm` function.  How do I go about and do this?

Comment: There are multiple answers for how to prevent the block from being cached, but I want it to be cached.  Just need to know how to invalidate the cacheing of my custom block

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When displaying information from a config object add it also as cache dependency to the render array.

For example in a preprocess hook:

```
  $config = \Drupal::config('mymodule.settings');
  $config_value = $config->get('some_field');
  $variables['some_field'] = [
    '#markup' => $config_value,
  ];
  // add the cache tag, so that the output gets invalidated when the config is saved
  \Drupal::service('renderer')->addCacheableDependency($variables, $config);
```

See [How to clear cache for config entity after making changes?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/266379/how-to-clear-cache-for-config-entity-after-making-changes)

**You don't need to change form submit because saving a config object automatically invalidates cache entries having this cache dependency (cache tag).**

---

Another example based on the block code from your answer and using a different method to add the cache tag:

```
  /**
   * Config settings.
   *
   * @var string
   */
  const SETTINGS = 'uw_cbl_special_alert.settings';
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function build() {
    $config = \Drupal::config(static::SETTINGS);
    return [
      '#markup' => $config->get('message'),
      '#cache' => [
        'tags' => $config->getCacheTags(),
      ],
    ];
  }
```

---

### Access caching

As asked in the comments, you can add cache dependencies to access results as well:

```
AccessResult::allowed()->addCacheableDependency($config)
AccessResult::forbidden()->addCacheableDependency($config)
```

Comment: The relevant cache tag in this instance is `config:my_module.settings`. See [Cache tags](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/cache-api/cache-tags) on d.o.

Comment: As a note, in case it's unclear, if you're building your custom block with your own plugin, you can add the cache dependencies in your `build()` method.

Comment: Your 2 examples do work for the message field, however, they do not work for my blockAccess.  My answer does. Hope you can read this...
protected function blockAccess(AccountInterface $account) {
   $config = \Drupal::config(static::SETTINGS);
   $display = $config->get('display_option');
   if ($display)
      return AccessResult::allowed();
    }
    return AccessResult::forbidden();}

Comment: Thanks for adding to Answer.  It works!

Answer (score -2):

Ok I believe I figured it out.  This works for me.

```
use Drupal\Core\Cache\Cache;
class ConfigurationForm extends ConfigFormBase {
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    // Invalidate block cache.
    Cache::invalidateTags(['config:block.block.{block_id_tag}']);
  }
}
```

I had to search the cachetags table in the database to find the block id tag.
In my case my custom block id in the annotation was `uw_cbl_special_alert` but the block id tag was `specialalert`

In case you are interested, code snippet from custom block

```
  /**
   * Config settings.
   *
   * @var string
   */
  const SETTINGS = 'uw_cbl_special_alert.settings';
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function build() {
    $config = \Drupal::config(static::SETTINGS);
    // Turn caching off as this is a special message and show never be cached.
    return [
      '#markup' => $config->get('message'),
    ];
  }
```

Comment: This is not a good way to do this. You should use the method in [4k4's answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/294840/48114).