# Excluding individual page components from caching

Tags: caching

I can't seem to find a straight answer online about whether it is possible to exclude just one component of a page from being cached.

My component appears on all pages of the site and comes from a custom theme function rendered in page.html.twig from the following in `mytheme_preprocess_page`:

```
$alerts_renderable = [
'#theme' => 'my_alerts',
];
$variables['alerts'] = $alerts_renderable;
```

I've tried adding `#cache => ['max-age' => 0]` in that render array to no effect. I read elsewhere that changing max-age has no effect on anonymous visitors. Has anyone had success in ever doing this?

The component is an alert bar that site admins can enter text via a settings page on the backend. That message appears in the alert bar on every page of the site. Currently, when admins change the message, it requires a cache clear for the new message to be publicly visible

Comment: You don't need cache max-age, you need the cache tag of the config object saved by the settings page.

Comment: See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/294839/how-to-clear-the-a-block-cache-programmically

Answer (score 0):

The current limitations on the `max-age` implementation [are documented, as are the workarounds](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/cache-api/cache-max-age#s-limitations-of-max-age).

> Until these (and perhaps other) issues are resolved, beware that setting max-age on a render array included in a page is insufficient to ensure that anonymous users will see a new version after the max-age as elapsed. In the meanwhile, the Cache Control Override contributed module tries to mitigate the problems. You might also have more luck setting a custom cache tag on pages with time-dependent content and invalidating those cache tags manually via hook_cron(). Good luck!

The paragraph above contains hyperlinks to the referenced resources when viewed on the documentation page.